# make only video player Landscape in uiviewcontroller on rotation ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, avplayer, landscape

This is my PlayerViewController Image>> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuWLA.jpg). On the top of this controller There is a video player.  I want all other viewcontrollers in portrait. As well as views other than player also should be in portrait always. When user rotate screen to landscape I just need the video player expand and rotate. VIDEO PLAYER ONLY.

But it looks ugly when I rotate. The whole view rotates. Image >> [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMekK.png)

Please help me to fix this.
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are the controls laid out for the view? Are you using storyboards and autolayout? Or are you doing all positioning/layout via code? If you are using storyboards, you can always have a separate layout for landscape vs. portrait.

Or, you can set up the autolayout constraints to change the videoplayer based on the screen size. That approach would depend on how you have the other controls set up though ...

Comment: I am using story board and auto layout. But putting some view overlays on top of the player. That's not an issue.

Comment: But When I rotate these views come in this dirty way. I need to keep all other views(dJ Name, time, Program Name) in portrait and only videoplayer should rotate.

Comment: Then, possibly your autolayout constraints are not set up properly to handle the job as you want it to work. I can take a look if you can upload the project somewhere but otherwise, it's hard to comment without knowing what you are doing :)

Comment: Okay I will try